# ¿Como quito el autoplay de un embed?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código html:

```
<embed width="320" height="50" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://www.globalhost.com.ve/shoutcast/reproductor3.swf?s=2&p=60" play="false" loop="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" menu="false" title="Streaming HD By GLOBALHOST" autoplay="false"></embed>
```

Tengo el código con `autoplay="false"` y aun así sigue reproduciéndose.

Comment: Te recomiendo sustituir la imagen por el código fuente. StackOverflow disponede mecanismos para colorear el código fuente. Piensa que si en algún momento la imagen deja de estar disponible este hilo no servirá absolutamente para nada.

Comment: firefox, por ahi no me ha funcionado el autoplay="false"

Comment: Por curiosidad: Te funciona la respuesta de Error404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar con `autostart="0"` o `autostart="1"`.

También puedes probar a quitar el valor de autoplay de la etiqueta para que no se cargue automáticamente.

Parece que los problemas en cuanto a asignarle `true` o `false` es debido a `Google Chrome` que no los detecta.

Referencia: [HTML embed autoplay=“false”, but still plays automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286541/html-embed-autoplay-false-but-still-plays-automatically)

Comment: he leido por ahi que `autoplay` no se le asigna `true`o `false`. Si está presente en la etiqueta significa `true` y si no está `false`. Lo vi por ahi, no lo  he probado

Comment: @lois6b Añadido. Lo había visto en la otra pregunta pero elegí la pregunta que más votada estaba.

Comment: Exacto @lois6b. Los atributos booleanos en html funcionan así, si están son `true`, si no están `false`. Lo mismo vale para `checked`, `selected`, etc.

Comment: Todo esto no funciona en Firefox... en Chrome funciona sin especificar nada...

Comment: @aldanux La verdad que no lo he podido probar aún ya que lo he puesto con el móvil. Luego cuando llegue a casa lo reviso más a fondo. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: @aldanux funciona igual en Firefox y en Chrome si se usa como los demás atributos booleanos: o se pone o no, sin añadir ningun valor.

Comment: @blonfu - haz probado el código del OP?

Comment: @aldanux, no. Igual he hablado muy rápido porque yo estaba pensando en la etiqueta `<video>` y el OP está usando `<embed>`.  En la especificación no aparece el atributo `autoplay` para la etiqueta `embed` así que dependerá de los navegadores si lo implementan o no y cómo.

Answer (score 0):

Por el simple hecho de estar el atributo ahí algunos navegadores lo tomarán como verdadero y lo ejecutarán.

Simplemente quita el atributo desde el html. O si te sirve mejor, por javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].removeAttribute("autoplay");
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba usando, a mi me sirvió en google chrome y pues avisa si te sirvió de algo

```
<video controls="" width="50%" height="50%" name="media"><source src="tuvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```